# Visual Basic - newbie question - unable to assign user input to a class property

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to take the user input and assign it to a property defined in a class. When I run the program, it asks for user input as expected, but displays a different result. Can someone point out where my mistake is ?

I was trying to base my simple program on this tutorial 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/vb-with-visual-studio
but trying to extend it to classes.

I am using the latest version of Visual Studio and Visual Basic. It's a visual basic Console App

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim ClassInstance As New Class1()
        Console.WriteLine("Input Property 1: ")
        ClassInstance.Property1 = Console.Read()
        Console.Write(ClassInstance.Property1)
        Console.ReadKey(True)

    End Sub

    Public Class Class1
        Public Property1 As Integer
        Public Property2 As Integer
    End Class

End Module
```

Expected output:

> "Input Property 1:"  |
>   User input 50 |
>   Output 50

Comment: " but displays a different result" - okay, you've told us what you expected to see. What different result *did* you see?

Comment: If I input 50, it gives 53! I can try inputting any other number but it gives anything but the number I just gave. Sometimes it's 53 and sometimes it's 49 etc.

Comment: `Console.Read` does not do what you apparently think it does.  What is does is read a SINGLE CHARACTER entered by the user and returns the Unicode point value of that character.  What you should be doing is calling `ReadLine` to get the entire text enterd by the user and then converting that to an `Integer` yourself.

Comment: By the way, your class has no properties.  Those two members are fields, not properties.  It makes no difference in this context but it will in others.  Use actual properties.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

[`Console.Read`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=netframework-4.7.2) reads the next *character* from the input, and gives you that character's code. If, for instance, you typed `5` at the prompt<sup>1</sup>, `Console.Read` would return 53. Why? Because that's the ASCII/Unicode code for that character (in Unicode terms, it's U+0035, which is the same number represented in hexadecimal).

If you want to read *multiple* characters and interpret them as an integer, you should a) be using something other than `Console.Read` to take the input and b) use [`Int32.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2) to try to turn it into a number (because users don't always give us the input we expect).

Something like:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim ClassInstance As New Class1()
        Console.WriteLine("Input Property 1: ")
        Dim inp = Console.ReadLine()
        Dim value as Int32
        If Int32.TryParse(inp, value) Then
          ClassInstance.Property1 = value
          Console.Write(ClassInstance.Property1)
          Console.ReadKey(True)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Class Class1
        Public Property1 As Integer
        Public Property2 As Integer
    End Class

End Module
```

(With apologies if I've made syntax errors - my VB's quite rusty)

In reality, you'd probably want to write some form of loop that prompts for user input and doesn't terminate until it successfully parses. I think `Do`/`While` would fit there - but if you're going to prompt the user more than once, you probably would want to extract the "Loop until valid input received" code into a function that takes the prompt as a parameter.

More reading - [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)/[Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode). For characters in the "7-bit ASCII" range, basic latin characters without accents, it doesn't make much difference which references you check

---

<sup>1</sup>And it doesn't matter if you carried on and typed any more characters, your program only asks for/gets one of them